# Java Swing графика double-координаты

Tags: java, swing, graphics

Graphics: `drawOval(int x, int y, int width, int height)` - существует ли аналог, но только с нецелыми координатами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650000/how-to-draw-a-circle-positioning-it-at-a-double-value-instead-of-a-int).

```
Ellipse2D.Double shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0.5, 0.5, 50, 50);
g.draw(shape);
```